# Layout redirect in zend Framework 2

Tags: authentication, layout, view, zend-framework2

Is it possible to redirect to a route in Layout.phtml in ZF2. I want to redirect to login page if the user is not logged in from layout.phtml

So far i have tried:

```
<?php $auth = new AuthenticationService();
                      if ($auth->hasIdentity()) {?>
                        <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo $this->url('home') ?>">
                        <?php echo $this->translate('Home') ?></a></li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo $this->url('login/process', array('action'=>'logout')) ?>"><?php echo $this->translate('Logout') ?></a></li>
                  <?php 
                     }  
                   else  
                    {
                   $this->_forward('login/process');

                     } ?>
```

its giving me error "get was unable to fetch or create an instance for _forward"

BOOTSTRAP CODE:

```
  public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('translator');
    $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
    $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
    $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    //nothing's available for non logged user, so redirect him to login page
    $eventManager->attach("dispatch", function($e) {
        $match = $e->getRouteMatch();
        $list = $this->whitelist;
                    // Route is whitelisted
                    $name = $match->getMatchedRouteName();
                    if (in_array($name, $list)) {
                        return;
                    }
        $sm = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
        $controller = $e->getTarget();
        $auth = $sm->get('AuthService');
        if (!$auth->hasIdentity() && $e->getRouteMatch()->getMatchedRouteName() !== 'login/process') {
            $application = $e->getTarget();

            $e->stopPropagation();
            $response = $e->getResponse();
            $response->setStatusCode(302);
            $response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Location', $e->getRouter()->assemble(array(), array('name' => 'login/process')));
            //returning response will cause zf2 to stop further dispatch loop

            return $response;
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not something that you wanna be doing inside your `layout.phtml`. Typically you want to hook in to an event that happens before the rendering. In ZF2, the earliest event to hook into that kind of stuff, where it makes sense to hook into, would be the route event. A good diagram of the process that's used in the Authorization-Module [BjyAuthorize](https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize) explains it quite well:

[image: Authorization-Workflow BjyAuthorize]

If you don't want to use the Module, you can minify what's happening there, too, like this:

```
//class Module
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $mvcEvent) 
{
    $eventManager = $mvcEvent->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE, array($this, 'onRoute'), -1000);
}

public function onRoute(MvcEvent $event) 
{
    $serviceLocator = $mvcEvent->getApplication()->getServiceLocator();
    // From this point onwards you have access to the ServiceLocator and can check
    // for an authenticated user and if the user is not logged in, you return a 
    // Response object with the appropriate ResponseCode redirected and that's it :)
}
```

Comment: well i have this in place but i have a few links that opens in divs and the redirect opens the login page in div as well when i want it to take me to login page altogether.

Comment: I don't understand the question-part of your comment.

Comment: when user logs in,User can click home and i am opening that page in a <div>. Now when the session expires and user clicks on home again, the redirect to login page opens in the same <div? as well. When i want it to redirect in the browser to login page. Does that make sense ?

Comment: Well, that's pretty much what my into is about. Of course you'll need some more code attached (as well as allow the Login route to actually be called without auth), but all in all that's what you're looking for ;)

Comment: i will post my bootstrap code in edit can you please see what need to be done there to make it function properly ?

Comment: So you're saying you're opening the link in a div? Does this mean you're making an AJAX request, grabbing the HTML response & appending it to a DIV? If this is the case, then the redirect in PHP is not going to work for you. An AJAX request is an entirely self contained request that does not affect the parent window. You would have to check the response and if it's a login page, then redirect using JavaScript.